# How to fix an image over the slider using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to fix an image above the slider, I've used the below code. It gets fixed but the problem is that, if I minimize or resize the browser, the image moves from that position and takes its own place.

CSS:

```
.imageover{
      background:transparent;
      bottom: 0;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 8;
     opacity:1.0!important
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="topbanner" width=1000px>
    <div class ="imageover">
        <img src="images/greendesign.png" width =350/>
    </div>
    <div id="sliderFrame">
        <div id="slider">
            <img src="images/slider1.png"/>
            <img src="images/slider2.jpg" />
            <img src="images/slider3.jpg" />
            <img src="images/slider4.jpg" />
            <img src="images/slider5.jpg" />
            <img src="images/slider6.jpg" />
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: share your `#sliderFrame` and `#slider` CSS

Comment: Please add details as the properties of `#sliderFrame` and `#slider` will affects cascading of both elements, relevant to each other...

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: fixed;` if this an image that you want fixed on a place on the page, and unaffected by scrolling.

```
.imageover{
  background: none;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 8;
  opacity: 1.0 !important
}
```

More on the `position` property [here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/).

Comment: it wont affect now i altered the question with my html too